# Recorrer JSON y diferenciar los campos nulos y vacios

Tags: php, json

Estoy haciendo un script en PHP, que me permita recorrer un JSON para hacerle debug cuando alguno de los tags este nulo, es problema es que al convertir el JSON a un array, los datos que estaban vacíos se convierten y quedan como nulos. Adjunto el código a continuación:

Este es el JSON:

```
$json = "{
"Comprobante": {
    "TipoComprobante": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Fecha": "2099-12-12",
    "Serie": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Folio": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Moneda": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Referencia": "",
    "ConceptoRef": "",
    "Descripcion": [
        {
            "Nombre": "Observaciones",
            "Valor": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        }
    ],
    "MetodoPago": [
        {
            "Codigo": "XX",
            "Valor": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        }
    ]
},
"Emisor": {
    "Identificacion": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "TipoIdentificacion": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "RazonSocial": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "NombreComercial": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Direccion": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Pais": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "email": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Department": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "CitySubdivisionName": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "CityName": "",
    "Descripcion": [
        {
            "Nombre": "Tipo De Regimen",
            "Valor": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        }
    ]
},
"Receptor": {
    "Identificacion": " XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "TipoIdentificacion": null,
    "RazonSocial": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "NombreComercial": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Direccion": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Pais": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "email": "",
    "Department": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "CitySubdivisionName": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "CityName": "",
    "Descripcion": [
        {
            "Nombre": "Sector Empresarial",
            "Valor": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        }
    ]
},
"Detalles": [
    {
        "Nombre": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "Cantidad": "1.00",
        "ValorUnitario": XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
        "Subtotal": XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
        "Total": XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX00,
        "Codigo": XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
        "Impuestos": "",
        "Descripcion": [
            {
                "Nombre": "Descuento",
                "Valor": 0
            },
            {
                "Nombre": "Observaciones",
                "Valor": ""
            }
        ]
    }
],
"Totales": {
    "Total": XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
    "SubTotal": XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
    "Impuestos": []
},
"DetallesComprobante": [
    {
        "Nombre": "Fecha Vencimiento",
        "Valor": "2099-12-31"
    }
]}";
```

Codigo PHP:

```
$debugJSON = json_decode($json);
foreach($debugJSON as $primerIndice => $primerValor){
    foreach($primerValor as $segundoIndice => $segundoValor){
        if($segundoValor == null){
            echo "El tag contenido en $primerIndice => $segundoIndice esta vacio o nulo<br>";
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El json_decode sí distingue los vacíos de los null:

```
<?php
$json = '{
"Comprobante": {
    "TipoComprobante": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Fecha": "2099-12-12",
    "Referencia": null,
    "ConceptoRef": ""

}}';

$decoded=json_decode($json);

var_dump($decoded);
```

Tu problema es que estás usando comparación `==` en vez de `===` por lo tanto ambos lados de la comparación se castean implícitamente. Puedes probar en línea de comando (`php -a`)

```
php > var_dump('' == null);
bool(true)
php > var_dump('' === null);
bool(false)
```

Comment: +1, El [operador de comparación igual](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php) (`eg: ==`) no comprueba el tipo de datos, en cambio el operador de comparación idéntico (`eg: ===`), si. [Aquí una demo](http://rextester.com/TLFC38985)

Comment: ¡Gracias amigo! Lo pude solucionar con ello.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, para resolver lo que mencionas es necesario validar con el operador tripe igual para que verifique tanto value como tipo de dato "===", el siguiente es un ejemplo de lo que menciono:

```
$myArr = array("John",
               null,
               "",
               array("John", null, "", "Sally"),
               "Sally");

$myJSON = json_encode($myArr);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($myJSON);
echo "</pre>";

$debugJSON = json_decode($myJSON);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($debugJSON);
echo "</pre>";


foreach($debugJSON as $primerIndice => $primerValor){
    foreach($primerValor as $segundoIndice => $segundoValor){
            if($segundoValor === null){
                echo "El tag contenido en $primerIndice => $segundoIndice esta nulo<br>";
            }else{
                if($segundoValor == ''){
                    echo "El tag contenido en $primerIndice => $segundoIndice esta con valores vacios<br>";
                }
            }           
        }

   }
```

Ya seria implementarlo según lo que se presenta en la estructura de tu Json y de esa manera identificas si es null o si es vacío diferenciandolos. Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.